# mysqli from within a class. It works, but am I doing it right?

Tags: php, class, mysqli

I have used an external php class provide MySQL related functions for some time. All good. Just recently I have changed to mysqli, and the adjustments I have made seem to work, but nobody else (as far as I can see) does it the same way, making me wonder whether I am doing it wrong! Can anyone confirm. Thanks. By the way, I am attempting to avoid MySQL injection, hence the use of prepared queries - Am I achieving what I want?

Here is my database initialization function, which is a method in the class 'page'

```
function initialize()
    // Get the database connection info from the settings file
    {
        $info = new settings();
        $memberserver   = $info->sqlserver;
        $memberuser     = $info->sqluser;
        $memberpass     = $info->sqlpass;
        $memberdatabase = $info->sqldatabase;

        // connect to database
        $this->link = new mysqli("localhost", $memberuser, $memberpass, $memberdatabase);
        mysqli_set_charset($this->link, "utf8");
        return($this->link);
     }
```

Then the php page calls the method, and performs a mysqli query as follows

```
$q = $page -> initialize();
$query ="INSERT INTO tablename (title, description, slug, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $q ->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $title, $desc, $slug, $date);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$page -> disconnect();
```

As I say, it works. But have I made a schoolboy error? As always, thanks for any/all replies!

Comment: if you don't get any type of (syntax) errors; *bravo!, you did it right*

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/